# JavaFX - Do I need a subscene or is there a better way to do this?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to write a javafx application where the UI behaves similar to the phone dialer on a cell phone. There will be a layout with a few buttons at the top that change the contents of the area below them. I've defined the layout of the parts that change in FXML files and they all load and work fine.

My question is how do I define the "area" that changes in the main FXML and how do I swap in the new contents in the button event handler?

My main FXML layout looks like this:

```
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER" hgap="20" vgap="10"
    fx:controller="application.Main" >

    <Button text="Dialer" alignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" 
        onAction="#handleModeAction" />

    <Button text="Log" alignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" 
        onAction="#handleModeAction" />

    <Button text="Contacts" alignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" 
        onAction="#handleModeAction" />

<!--    
What goes here??
-->

</GridPane>
```

I read through the previous posts that looked similar but none looks quite like I thought it worked.

Thanks for any pointers
dave

Comment: Depends on how you want to display the info in the "area". A `SubScene` most likely isn't needed.

Comment: You can put any `Node` there. For example, a `VBox` would work; and when you need to change that part of the UI, just update its children.

Comment: I have modified the fxml and added this:

 <VBox 
 GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
 GridPane.columnSpan="3" 
 fx:id="appPane" />

I've tried casting the appPane vbox into a Node but I don't see a way to replace the children. 

The definitions and the scenes are declared in the Application class and set to the correct values in the start function. 

Thank you